# Добавление своих курсоров на сайт html css

Tags: html, css, cursor

Можно ли в браузере отображать свои анимированные курсоры? формата .ani ? Например используя .png или .cur все работает отлично, при указании .ani курсор вообще не изменяется. Конвертировал .ani в .gif, работает но не во всех браузерах и просто картинкой, без анимации. Как можно вообще использовать анимированные курсоры?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант, курсор можно эмулировать самому, с какими угодно размерами и картинками:

(но может быть заметен лаг, потому что в отличие от элементов системный курсор движется независимо от отрисовки кадров браузером)

```js
const cursor = document.querySelector('.cursor');

document.addEventListener( 'mouseenter', event => {
  cursor.style.display = 'block';
});

document.addEventListener( 'mouseleave', event => {
  cursor.style.display = 'none';
});

document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', event => {
  cursor.style.transform = `translate(${event.pageX}px, ${event.pageY}px)`;
});
```

```css
html {
  cursor: none;
}

.cursor {
  display: none;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1000000;
  pointer-events: none;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/7o9RS.gif) no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="cursor"></div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Хочу отметить, что данный способ вызовет баг, из-за того, что `.cursor` имеет свой таргет. К блоку `.cursor` я бы советовал применить `cursor-pointer: none`, а ещё лучше полифилл

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 вы правы, добавил свойство, но этот ответ не претендует на исчерпывающее решение, я надеюсь что люди не просто копипастят это как полностью боевой вариант )

Comment: Хочется в это верить)